# Error con versión de PHP al intentar integrar CheckOut pro de mercadopago

Tags: php, mercadopago, composer

Bien, tengo mi pagina dee ventas corriendo y funcionando... salvo por la parte de pago, en este caso uso como metodo de pago [Check out pro de mercadopago](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/en/guides/online-payments/checkout-pro/introduction) el cual cuando intento acceder me arroja el siguiente error: `Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.0".` Ya se que necesito cambiar la version de PHP de mi hosting, pero en este caso no me deja actualizar a la version 8.0.0, la version maxima es la 7.4 FPM... no se como solucionar esto, alguna ayuda?

Comment: Intenta descargando o instalando desde el [repositorio en GitHub](https://github.com/mercadopago/sdk-php), está disponible para versiones >= 5.6 y >= 7.1

Comment: Ya probé con reemplazar los archivos por los del repositorio... pero nada @Triby

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con _"pero nada"_? Puedes descargar los archivos, incluirlos en tu proyecto o usar composer desde línea de comandos y estando en el directorio donde quieres que se descarguen.

Comment: "pero nada" lo utilice para expresar que sigue sin cambios, me sigue apareciendo exactamente el mismo error @Triby

Comment: El problema es que no especificas qué fue lo que hiciste, si descargaste un archivo comprimido o instalaste mediante _composer_ con los comandos que aparecen ahí. En cualquiera de estos dos casos, ya no debe aparecer el error por la versión de PHP igual o mayor que 8.